# Dask; build ND lazy array

Tags: dask

I'm attempting to build a 5D (lazy) array from the difference in position vectors between the discretized surface and interior of a sphere.
Using for loops, it's a straightforward problem (just nested 5 levels deep -- two for the surface positions and 3 for the interior positions).
I'm attempting to use einsum for much of the actual computation, but am having real trouble getting my head around how to build the 5D array in Dask.

Example:

DX_ijlmn = SX_ij - VX_lmn
where DX is the difference in x components between the surface (SX_ij) and the interior volume (VX_lmn).

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Assume that DX will not fit in memory (eventually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have dask arrays **SX** and **VX** with shapes (*i*,*j*) and (*l*,*m*,*n*) respectively, and want to compute a kind of "outer" difference between them, resulting in array **DX** of shape (*i*,*j*,*l*,*m*,*n*)?  In that case, what you're looking for is

```
DX = SX[:,:,None,None,None] - VX[None,None,:,:,:]
```

This would coerce **SX** and **VX** into the shapes (*i*,*j*,1,1,1) and (1,1,*l*,*m*,*n*) respectively, which would allow the subtraction to broadcast properly over the dimensions.  The resulting dask array **DX** would have shape (*i*,*j*,*l*,*m*,*n*), and would be lazy in nature (values would not be actually calculated until needed).

Comment: Yes. That is pretty close to what I eventually came up with. I used dask.array.broadcast_to() rather than your *much* clearer and more transparent syntax. I'll now go try to see if things perform better via your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without more information, but you may want to take a look at [Dask Delayed](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html) and the [documentation on using Dask Delayed with Dask Array](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#using-dask-delayed).  This is the usual fallback for complex problems.

There may be a simpler solution to your problem, but unfortunately I don't understand your question well enough to provide one.